# Error con scrollview en Recyclerview Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, scroll, volley

Tengo un recyclerview de 3 items cada fila, a éste lo lleno desde un api con paginación (cada 12 items , solo imágenes), el consumo del web service es correcto pero mi problema es que cuando hago scroll por el recyclerview se traba o se congela, mi pregunta es como hago que mi scroll sea más fluido asi como el de instagram que cuando se hace scroll no se congela. Este es mi código

Activity

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_imagenes,container,false);
        pagina = 1;
        rv = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_todospedidosctrl);
        progress_bar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.ProgressTheme);
        glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
        rv.setLayoutManager(glm);
        adapter = new RV_Imagenes_Adapter(getContext(), obj_pedidos);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = glm.getChildCount();
                totalItems = glm.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = glm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems) == totalItems){
                    isScrolling = false;
                    pagina += 1;
                    api_imagenes(2);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Adaptador

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RV_Imagenes_Adapter.MyView holder, final int position) {
        holder.lbl_detalle.setText(mData.get(position).getNombre());
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(Constants.img_url+""+mData.get(position).getImagen())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                .dontAnimate()
                .into(holder.imageview);
        holder.cv_lista_imagenes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(detectarRed.tengo_red()){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"No posees conexión a internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Como pueden ver es un simple recycler view, en si todo esta bien tan solo el scrollview falla la idea es que sea mas fluido o suave como instagram o twitter, etc.

De antemano les agradezco

Comment: Mientras haces el `scroll` y te sucede este problema, te sale algún error o warning en el `log`?

Comment: La verdad no, tan solo veo mensajes como esto:

APS: play type is 1 | APS: play type is 2 | Do partial code cache collection, code=1509KB, data=906KB | After code cache collection, code=1509KB, data=906KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 4MB

Comment: Mi error esta en esto glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3); le puse el valor de 1 enves de 3 y funciona correctamente, Que puedo hacer?

Comment: intenta usar el `GridLayoutManager` asi `GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2,
GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);` varia los números y la orientación

Comment: no aun no me funciona

Comment: creo que mi error esta all llmar el metodo api_imagenes(2);

Comment: has intentado con otra librería de consumo de servicios?, Retrofit 2 por ejemplo, quizás tu problema este en los tiempos de respuesta.

Comment: si me responde  rapido,  no tienes algun tutoral que pueda seguir?

Comment: no, lamentablemente para lo que solicitas no tengo un tutorial o algo parecido :(

Comment: Gracias de todos modos amigo :D